# How do I invoke other tasks from my custom task *before* my task code runs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I'm trying to create a custom task in grunt that automatically invokes its "prerequisites". I'm not sure on how to do that. The [Grunt.js docs](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#custom-tasks) show this example:

```
grunt.registerTask('foo', 'My "foo" task.', function() {
  // Enqueue "bar" and "baz" tasks, to run after "foo" finishes, in-order.
  grunt.task.run('bar', 'baz');
  ... // Other stuff here
});
```

I don't want to "enqueue `bar` and `baz` after `foo`", I want to execute them right there, where the `grunt.task.run` line is, so they get executed before my "Other stuff".

How do I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think your only way to do it currently would be via creating and additional task

```
grunt.registerTask('fooTask', 'My "foo" task.', function() {
  grunt.task.requires('bar'); // make sure bar was run and did not fail
  grunt.task.requires('baz'); // make sure bar was run and did not fail
  ... // Other stuff here
});

grunt.registerTask('foo', 'My "foo" sequence.', ['bar', 'baz', 'fooTask']);
```

Comment: Well, that's kindof disappointing. At least I will not waste more time looking for a solution. Thanks!